# How to use months as columns from date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a simple table with types, numbers and dates:

```
type | number | date
--------------------
  A  |      2 | 15-MAY-2015
  A  |      1 | 15-APR-2015
  B  |      9 | 03-DEC-2015
```

I need to add the numbers based on the type. But what I'm having problems with is that the resulting table needs to have the months as columns:

```
type | April | May | December
-----------------------------
  A  |     1 |   2 |       0
  B  |     0 |   0 |       9
```

How can I use the month names as columns?

I managed to get the names of the months using this function `TO_CHAR(table.date, 'Month') AS month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option (sample data from line #1 - 5):

```
SQL> with test (type, num, datum) as
  2    (select 'A', 2, date '2015-05-15' from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 1, date '2015-04-15' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 9, date '2015-12-03' from dual
  5    )
  6  select type,
  7    max(case when to_char(datum, 'mm') = '04' then num else 0 end) as april,
  8    max(case when to_char(datum, 'mm') = '05' then num else 0 end) as may,
  9    max(case when to_char(datum, 'mm') = '12' then num else 0 end) as december
 10  from test
 11  group by type
 12  order by type;

T      APRIL        MAY   DECEMBER
- ---------- ---------- ----------
A          1          2          0
B          0          0          9

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, this almost solves my problem. The issue is that I need to sum the values, but your code only replaces the number by num. Sorry, because in my example, you couldn't see the numbers being added.

Comment: In that case, instead of MAX use SUM function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT type,
         num,
         EXTRACT( MONTH FROM dt ) AS month
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT (
  SUM( num ) FOR month IN (
     1 AS January,
     2 AS February,
     3 AS March,
     4 AS April,
     5 AS May,
     6 AS June,
     7 AS July,
     8 AS August,
     9 AS September,
    10 AS October,
    11 AS November,
    12 AS December
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( type, num, dt ) AS
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2015-05-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2015-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 9, DATE '2015-12-03' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TYPE | JANUARY | FEBRUARY | MARCH | APRIL |  MAY | JUNE | JULY | AUGUST | SEPTEMBER | OCTOBER | NOVEMBER | DECEMBER
> :--- | ------: | -------: | ----: | ----: | ---: | ---: | ---: | -----: | --------: | ------: | -------: | -------:
> B    |    null |     null |  null |  null | null | null | null |   null |      null |    null |     null |        9
> A    |    null |     null |  null |     1 |    2 | null | null |   null |      null |    null |     null |     null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd4f9985c8db0ce65c3fbbd8facbc7c9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SYS_REFCURSOR` for a SQL Statement of Conditional Aggregation within a stored function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Totals_For_Months RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN

  SELECT LISTAGG('SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR("date",''mm'') = '''||LPAD(level,2,0)||
        ''' THEN "number" END ) AS 
        '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(level,2,0)||'-01','mm-dd'),'Month'),',') 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level)
    INTO v_cols
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 12; 

  v_sql := 'SELECT type,'||v_cols||
             ' FROM tab
             GROUP BY type'; 

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

in order to use month names as columns(*without considering the year, presumably remaining in only one year period*)

and then call as

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Totals_For_Months;
PRINT rc
```